# Runuser missing w option

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get [`genie`](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) up and running on WSL 2 (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) and am running into an issue where `runuser` was given the `w` option by `genie` but `runuser` sees that as an invalid option. [This man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/runuser.1.html) shows that it exists, but this [Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/runuser.1.html) doesn't have the `w` option.

Is there a reason why it is not included in Ubuntu's version of `runuser`? Also is there a way to workaround this issue? What is recommended in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my mistake; in the course of fixing some uid issues with an earlier release of genie, I took a dependency on runuser and since I develop primarily on Debian, didn't notice that this broke Ubuntu 18.04 compatibility.

*Mea culpa; mea maxima culpa.*

Since removing *runuser -w* from genie would cause regressions, my current recommendation for pre-19.04 Ubuntu is to use *genie -c bash* instead of *genie -s* where necessary; an imperfect workaround, but one which should work in most cases. I have documented this in the genie README.

- Alistair, genie maintainer

Answer (score 0):

runuser is a command that appeared in util-linux 2.23.

[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/util-linux) ships [util-linux 2.31](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/util-linux-locales)

In the util-linux 2.31 [Release Notes](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.31/v2.31.1-ReleaseNotes) it doesn't have the runuser command yet.

Comment: From what I have been able to figure out, the latest version of Ubuntu, 19.04, does have runuser's w option. So does that mean 19.04 has a version of util-linux where runuser has the w option? Which version does 19.04 ship with? Do you know if it is possible to get that version on 18.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 uses the util-linux version 2.33 unfortunately this version also doesn't contain the runuser command in the release notes you can check it here https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.33/v2.33-ReleaseNotes

Comment: I can confirm that it does have the option in 19.04, although I don't know why it isn't showing up in the release notes. The release notes for version 2.33 does mention the whitelist-enivornment option being added to su, and the man pages show that runuser now has it too, so maybe it was added but they forgot to mention it.

Comment: So apparently su and runuser are related, with runuser being compiled from the same source as su, with some exceptions. https://superuser.com/a/1145014/1004009 This would explain why this option was added to su and showed up in runuser

Comment: So now is it possible for 2.33 to be installed on 18.04 easily?

Comment: If it's not mentioned in the release notes then it's not present  as simple as that.They don't forget things to add